# how to know which button was clicked in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

If I have a search method that allows a user to search for a plant, then the list of the possible plants will appear and if the user clicks on a plant it will transfer them to a plant info page or a form to add it to their list based on which button the user was click.. so my question is how to know which button was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The button that calls the search method should pass the plant id or the Plant object as a parameter. This way, the method will carry the plant info.

Answer (score 0):

Your list widget presumably will create the button for each plant, so it already knows which plant is being clicked. Pass the plant record inside the onPressed action

```dart
//inside whatever builds a listitem for each plant result
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListItem(
    title: Text(plant.name),
    subtitle: TextButton(
      child: Text("some ${plant.name} action"),
      onPressed: () => PlantDetailWidget(plant),
    ),
  );
}
```